# Does somebody know a way to get the option 'print in color' more quickly in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

Does somebody know a way to get the option 'print in color' more quickly in MS Word?

My organisation resets the defaults for printing in black and white. Or in any case: every new day I log in the office, the settings are back to black and white. And I like it that wat.  But sometimes I have to print in color, and I wonder whether there is a more easy way to get to print it in color then I do now.

The process I follow now is the following:

I click on 'Print Preview and Print' (which is the equivalent op pressing CTRL+P)

```
I go to 'Printer Properties',
I go to the tab 'Color'
I select 'Colors'
I select 'OK'
I select 'Print'.
```

For eample: is there a way to get a shortcut in the Print screen (where yopu get by pressing CTRL+P)where to select for 'Print in colors'? For example there are already shortcuts for how may pages per sheet, etc.

Is there some way to get a shortcut there regarding color?

Comment: If you save the Word document after printing in colour once, it should retain that setting in the document itself, so next time it will still print in colour regardless of the setting at printer-driver level. This even works if you give the document to someone else as long as that person uses the same printer (the printername in Windows must be identical on the other computer for that to work). Most Office application (e.g. Excel, Powerpoint) work the same way.

Comment: though not an answer to my question, a good tip. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a toolbar macro that automates that action, and then assign it to a new button on the toolbar. Full instructions on the creation of macros within word is available here. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c

A macro automates lengthy tasks and makes them a toolbar button, or even a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer, could you please give a bit more details?

Comment: thanks. I have to do some thinking about how to het it in a macro, but I'm sure this will do the trick somehow. Thanks! (I still wonder why I haven't thought about this...)

Comment: Added extra macro creation information